# Error parsing attribute 'enableEventValidation': Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not have a public property named 'enableEventValidation'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Not seen this error discussed previously here (see subject line), maybe someone has run into the same problem.
I have `enableEventValidation = "False"` set for the `<page>` tag in my web.config file.
As I try to build my web app project on VS2010, I receive this error , rendering me unable to continue with my debugging of the app.
The page in question does not have enableEvenValidation set in its Page directive.

Any ideas out there on this one ?

Appreciate the feedback

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `EnableEventValidation`?

Comment: Hopefully it was just a typo, but the correct tag for that attribute is `<pages>`, not `<page>`.

Answer (score 0):

The section name should be `pages` (plural):

```
<pages enableEventValidation="true" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check a few things:

- Your application is at least .NET 2.0. The `EnablePageValidation` attribute didn't exist until .NET 2.0. I'm assuming it is since you're using VS2010.
- You don't have any typos. The correct place in the web.config file for that change is:

  ```
  <system.web>
      <pages enableEventValidation="False" />
  </system.web>
  ```
- According to the error message, an `enableEventValidation` property is missing. In C#, property names are case-sensitive. Whatever reflection is happening under the hood is using a lower-case `e` instead of an `E` on the property name.